# if 0 qty in custom options dropdown hide in product page in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

this product already stock out in magento backend....
[image]
if 0 qty in custom options dropdown hide in product page in magento
[image]

this code:- try but not work

```
<?php
                $product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();

                $productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product_id);

                foreach ($productCollection->getOptions() as $value) {

                    $values = $value->getValues();
                    foreach ($values as $values) {
                        //print_r($values->getData());
                        echo $values->getQty();
                        if($values=="0")
                        {

                        }
                        }
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            $product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
            $productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product_id);
            foreach ($productCollection->getOptions() as $value) {
                $values = $value->getValues();
                foreach ($values as $value) {
                    echo $value->getQty();
                    if($value->getQty() == '0')
                    {

                    }
                    }
                $i++;
            }
```